# Unable to access element within page

Tags: python, selenium

[Form Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkAXJ.png)
[HTML Inspect Code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NKdp.png)

I'm trying to access an element within a page. Cannot give out the exact page link owing to security concerns. I'm writing a python program that uses selenium to access the element first name in the screenshot shown above. The name is grayed out at first and whenever a user clicks on it, the text becomes black and can be edited.

The field simply does not seem to be visible to the program and the program fails with an element not found exception. I've used a wait method for the element to be visible but it just times out. I've tried waiting for it to be clickable, and I have tried injecting javascript to make the display style = block. None of this seems to work. I've researched extensively on StackOverflow and none of the options there seem to work for me. I spoke to the front-end developers and they tell me that apart from the div style display, there's nothing else they can think of because the element is visible in the DOM.

Does anybody know how I can access this element?

Comment: just to clarify, in the screenshot, when you click on the name 'Testy', the text box becomes editable, else it's just greyed out?

Comment: also, can you add the code that you have tried so far

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: A couple of checks. (1) are you able to find the parent element? You could use classname "edit_mode". (2) Did you check whether the elements might be inside an iframe? If they are, Selenium needs to be switched to that iframe before it can find anything inside it.

Comment: Clarifications:
When I click on Test the text box becomes editable, else, it's grayed out. The elements are not inside a frame. I tried using classname edit_mode, but that didn't work. I tried using just the text Testy but that didn't work either.
here's my code:
self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@name, '{}')]".format(field)
field is a parameter passed to my function and the value being passed is first_name

Answer (score 0):

[Resolved] Turns out there was a javascript code that would change the DOM whenever another button was clicked. So, all I had to do was re-query the DOM and then the element was visible. Thanks very much to all those who took the time to answer this question.