# Python & Selenium / XING: find_element works 1st time, not 2nd on iteration

Tags: python, selenium, xing

Been on it two days now: Trying to automate sending a contact request to several people in a search result with a message. After login and search, iterating the add-buttons works and `add_btn.click()` opens the pop-ups. Only in the first instance, however, I successfully `try:` `find_element_by_name` to access the `<textarea name="reason">` and can do `element.send_keys()`to insert my message. In the second iteration, I cannot seem to access the message form, although, when I print the iteration of `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@name]")`, `<textarea name="reason">` is present.

I try to catch the most common exceptions but that does not seem to work.

Can anyone explain pls, 1) what is happening here and why the call for all named elements can list the textarea, but my specific call to find it does not work, and 2) how I could solve this problem. Thanks!

Here is the part of my code for going through search results:

```
def contact(text):
    add_btns=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.searchResult-actionLink.foundation-icon-core-contact-add.contact-lightbox-link")     
    i=0
    wanted=6   
    for add_btn in add_btns:
       i+=1       
       try:
          add_btn.click()
          time.sleep(2)
          driver.save_screenshot("add%s.png" % (i,))        ###works on every turn!
          elems=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@name]")
          for elem in elems:
             print i, elem.tag_name, elem.get_attribute("name")  ###prints out 'textarea reason' on every turn!                      

          try:
             mssgbrd = driver.find_element_by_name("reason")
             print "mssgbrd found"                          ###prints only on first round???
             mssgbrd.send_keys(text)                                
             driver.save_screenshot("request%s.png" % (i,))             
          except ElementNotVisibleException:
              print "not visible"
          except StaleElementReferenceException:
              print "stale"              
          except NoSuchElementException:
              print "no such element"              
          except TimeoutException:
              print "timed out"
          except:
              print "something else happens"    


          request=driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
          (By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#crl-button-send-request > a.element-form-button-solid-lime"))) 
          try:
            request.click()
            time.sleep(3)            
          except TimeoutException:
             print("Button not found!")
             driver.save_screenshot("ButtonError%s.png" % (i,))

       except:
           print "Request not working"                      ###prints out on second round and after
           driver.save_screenshot("xibit%s.png" % (i,))     ###get's called on second round and after
```

When I run this code, after the first successful iteration I keep getting the last exception "Request not working" for all other iterations. I have tested with `close_button.click()` closing the pop-up instead of sending the request - here the second iteration was successful.

Comment: Does it print "something else happens"? Can I access your app? I think you may need to wait for the reason element.

Comment: @Buaban No, it only prints the last exception. It's actually not an app, I am logging in to their website and use Selenium/PhantomJS to automate browsing and sending text. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44293962/unable-to-access-element-within-page) about a possibility of an element changing after clicking a specific button, maybe that's what happens? But I am unaware of how to catch/resolve this. I have also tried `driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "reason")))` giving me the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I still can't assess, what the problem was, but this is how it got resolved. Maybe someone more experienced than me knows what happened.

In my original code I had a line with `text=unicode(text.decode("utf-8"))` just before

```
try:
   mssgbrd = driver.find_element_by_name("reason")
   print "mssgbrd found"
```

I cut it out for brevity in my post here, as I thought it would not be important. Boy, was I wrong... When experimenting, I added two instances of `print time.ctime()` to find out about a possible timeout or waiting period; one just between the utf-8-decoding and the `try:`-block, and one after the critical `mssgbrd = driver.find_element_by_name("reason")`.

When running the code, *on the second iteration none of them were printed*, meaning that somehow the code stopped *even before* trying `mssgbrd = driver.find_element_by_name("reason")`just were the decoding took place. I then moved the decoding to the top of the function and was able to successfully send two invite messages. So basically, the function in my question should work fine, and if you were to add decoding the first lines would look like this:

```
def contact(text):
    text=unicode(text.decode("utf-8"))
    add_btns=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.searchResult-actionLink.foundation-icon-core-contact-add.contact-lightbox-link")     
    i=0
    wanted=6   
    for add_btn in add_btns:
       i+=1       
       try:
          add_btn.click()
          time.sleep(2)
          driver.save_screenshot("add%s.png" % (i,))                    
          elems=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@name]")
          for elem in elems:
             print i, elem.tag_name, elem.get_attribute("name") 
          try:
             mssgbrd = driver.find_element_by_name("reason")
             print "mssgbrd found"                         
             mssgbrd.send_keys(text)                                
             driver.save_screenshot("request%s.png" % (i,))             
          except:
```

I would love to understand, however, what happened here.